# Multiple level of @Inject in a Jersey application

Tags: google-app-engine, dependency-injection, jersey-2.0

I have a Jersey 2 application. A resource is using one of my service class using `@Inject` and all goes ok.

The binding configuration:

```
    class MyApp extends ResourceConfig {

       register(new AbstactBinder() {

          @Override
          protected void configure() {

              bind(PrimaryService.class).to(PrimaryService.class);
          }
       });
    }
```

The resource class:

```
   @Path("/example"); 
   class Resource {

      @Inject
      PrimaryService service;

      @GET
      public Response get() {

         //Consume service class
      }
   }
```

Everything works as expected.

**BUT what if I need another @Inject in the PrimaryService class?**

I added the binding:

```
 bind(PrimaryService.class).to(PrimaryService.class);
 bind(SecondaryService.class).to(SecondaryService.class);
```

And, in the PrimaryService class, I have:

```
class PrimaryService {

   @Inject
   SecondaryService secondary;

   public void someMethod() {

      //Consume secondary
   }
}
```

But, I have an exception telling me that dependency is usatisfied.

I'm using Jersey2 on Google AppEngine instance.